C++ sort structure of vectors
I have the following structure:
struct Trade {
    vector<long> id;
    vector<double> price;
    vector<double> quantity;
};

How could I sort that structure according to the ID, please?

I would recommend to reorganize data structure first. Have one vector of structure which has three fields. Then sorting this vector will be easy.

At which point you can use std::sort with a lambda as a comparator.

Offtopic: people go to jail for using floats to handle money.

Something like: std::sort(vec.begin(), vec.end(), [](auto &a, auto &b) { return a.id == b.id ? 0 : a.id > b.id ? 1 : -1; });

@MarekR what should I use instead ? ^^

@MarekR I am using a struct of vectors instead cause later I'd be using eigen to do rolling functions. I originally did a vector of structure, but then the rolling function is more efficient with vectors of double than vectors of struct

@Chris this won't sort in accordance the price and quantity vectors though ?

No, for that you'd need something like std::sort(vec.begin(), vec.end(), [](auto &a, auto &b) { return a.id < b.id ? -1 : a.id > b.id ? 1 : a.price < b.price ? -1 : a.price > b.price ? 1 : a.quantity < b.quantity ? -1 : a.quantity > b.quantity ? 1 : 0; });`

Instead of floats use fixed point arithmetic and store the money in the smallest possible denomination. For example if we're talking US Dollars, we'd store and operate on the money in pennies, 1 one-hundredth of a dollar. This is because floating point math gets weird and imprecise around the edges.
